# linear algebra equation system solution set

Tags: linear-algebra

$$X + 2Y - 3Z = 7  \\
2X + 3Y + Z = 2  \\
X + Y - 2Z = 0$$

Hello, I couldn't get out of solving the question. I am confused. Can you help me?
linear algebra equation system solution set

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: x = -14 y = 12 z = 0

Comment: I made the answers like this, but I don't know if it's true

Comment: @MehmetKömürcüoğlu: please abstain from such useless comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&-3&7\\2&3&1&2\\1&1&-2&0\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&-3&7\\0&-1&7&-12\\0&-1&1&-7\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&-3&7\\0&-1&7&-12\\0&0&-6&5\end{array}$$

gives $$Z=-\frac56.$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x+2y-3z=7\\
\\
2x+3y+z=2\\
\\
x+y-2z=0
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Swap equation 1 with equation 2:

$$
\begin{cases}
2x+3y+z=2\\
\\
x+2y-3z=7\\
\\
x+y-2z=0
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Subtract $\frac{1}{2}\times\left(\text{equation 1}\right)$ from equation 2:

$$
\begin{cases}
2 x+3 y+z=2\\
\\
\frac{y}{2}-\frac{7z}{2}=6\\
\\
x+y-2z=0
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Multiply equation 2 by $2$:

$$
\begin{cases}
2 x+3 y+z=2\\
\\
y-7 z=12\\
\\
x+y-2z=0
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Subtract $\frac{1}{2}\times\left(\text{equation 1}\right)$ from equation 3:

$$
\begin{cases}
2 x+3 y+z=2\\
\\
y-7 z=12\\
\\
-\frac{y}{2}-\frac{5z}{2}=-1
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Multiply equation 3 by $-2$:

$$
\begin{cases}
2 x+3 y+z=2\\
\\
y-7 z=12\\
\\
y+5z=2
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

> Now: Subtract equation 2 from equation 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the system as $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\1 & 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \\ Z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}7 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

As Det($\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\1 & 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}) = 6 \ne 0$ the system as a unique solution given by $\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \\ Z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\1 & 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}7 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$